# Finding torrents and adding to torrent Clients using python script

Tags: python

I have written a python script that takes search keywords as arguments and finds matching torrents on popular torrent sites, downloads the torrent file then adds it to a torrent-client (in this case uTorrent). See example command below

```
python script.py keywrod1 keyword2 ...
```

Currently it searches torrents on following sites

1. http://yts.ag
2. http://extratorrent.cc
3. http://rar.bg
4. http://torrentproject.se

Right now my script looks like this

```
import urllib.request
import os
import tqdm
import sys
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree
import time

# Configurations
download_torrent_file = True
add_to_client = True
verbose = True
max_per_source = 4
# Path string must include quotations for later use in 'os.system()' call
torrent_client_path = '"C:/Users/Sayam Qazi/AppData/Roaming/uTorrent/uTorrent.exe"'


search_key = ""
feed_servers = ["yts.ag", "rar.bg", "ex.to"]

# this is where the .torrent files will be downloaded
# this must exist in filesystem prior to the execution of script.
download_destination = ""
matches_found = 0
torrent_urls = []
torrent_files = []


# extract search key and destination from command line args
def process_args(args):
    if len(args) == 3:
        global download_destination
        global search_key
        search_key = args[1]
        download_destination = args[2]
        # add a / at the end of the destination path
        if download_destination[-1:] != '/':
            download_destination += '/'
        if not os.path.exists(download_destination):
            print("Provided Download destination does not exist")
            sys.exit(0)
    else:
        print("Incomplete command.")
        print("Correct syntax : squirrel.py [search_key] [destination]")
        sys.exit(0)


# generate RSS provider specific URL you can add as many as you wish
def build_url(feed_server, key):
    if feed_server == "yts.ag":
        return "https://www.yts.ag/rss/" + key + "/all/all/0"
    elif feed_server == "rar.bg":
        return "https://www.rarbg.to/rssdd.php?category=movies"
    elif feed_server == "ex.to":
        return "http://extratorrent.cc/rss.xml?type=search&search=" + key
    else:
        return ""


def extract_from_tree(feeder, tree):
    global torrent_files
    global torrent_urls
    counter = 0
    if feeder == "yts.ag":
        items = tree[0].findall("item")
        for item in items:
            counter += 1
            if not counter < 4:
                break
            title = item[0].text.replace('/', ' ')
            if verbose:
                print("[yts.ag] : " + title)
            url = item[5].attrib["url"]
            torrent_urls.append(url)
            torrent_files.append(title + ".torrent")
    elif feeder == "rar.bg":
        items = tree[0].findall("item")
        for item in items:
            title = item[0].text.replace('/', ' ')
            if not search_key.lower() in title.lower():
                continue
            if not counter < 4:
                break
            counter += 1
            if verbose:
                print("[rar.bg] : " + title)
            url = item[2].text
            torrent_urls.append(url)
            torrent_files.append(title + ".torrent")
    elif feeder == "ex.to":
        items = tree[0].findall("item")
        for item in items:
            counter += 1
            if not counter < 4:
                break
            title = item[0].text.replace('/', ' ')
            if verbose:
                print("[ex.to] : " + title)
            url = item[4].attrib["url"]
            torrent_urls.append(url)
            torrent_files.append(title + ".torrent")


def fetch_torrent_files():
    for feeder in feed_servers:
        if verbose:
            print("FETCH FROM : " + feeder)
        request_headers = {"User-Agent": "Magic browser"}
        print(build_url(feeder, search_key))
        request = urllib.request.Request(build_url(feeder, search_key), headers=request_headers)
        response = ""
        with urllib.request.urlopen(request) as f:
            response = f.read()
        if len(response) > 0:
            tree = xml.etree.ElementTree.fromstring(response)
            extract_from_tree(feeder, tree)

def download_torrents():
    if verbose:
        print("[Squirrel] Downloading .torrent files")
    if not os.path.isdir(download_destination):
        print("Download destination does not exist")
        sys.exit(0)
    for url,filename in zip(torrent_urls,torrent_files):
        if verbose:
            print("Downloading : " + filename)
        stream = requests.get(url,stream=True)
        with open(download_destination + filename , "wb") as handle:
            for data in tqdm.tqdm(stream.iter_content()):
                handle.write(data)

def enqueue_torrents():
    if verbose:
        print("[Squirrel] Enqueuing torrents")
    if not os.path.isdir(download_destination):
        print("Download destinaiton deos not exist")
        sys.exit(0)
    for filename in torrent_files:
        if verbose:
            print("Enqueuing : " +  filename)
        os.system('"' + torrent_client_path + ' "' + download_destination + filename + '""')

process_args(sys.argv)
fetch_torrent_files()
if download_torrent_file:
    download_torrents()
if add_to_client:
    enqueue_torrents()
```

My concerns lie in two functions `build_url(feed_server, key)`, `enqueue_torrent()` and `extract_from_tree(feeder, tree)`. As you can see `build_url` and `extract_from_tree` methods have different logic to get torrent from different torrent sites. As I adds support for multiple sites it will get uglier especially the `extract_from _tree()` function.Is there a better way to accomplish this than if-else. I am looking for more readable/understandable way.

About the `enqueue_torrent` function it just adds torrents to uTorrent client. I also need it to be more sophisticated. Like when it adds a torrent, uTorrent opens up with the add torrent dialog. I found a workaround that i can disable that dialog. Is there a command line arg for utorrent that skips that dialog.

Overall I also need some advice to make this code more readable/understandable/manageable.